# How to collect mob spawners

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have tried blowing up multiple mob spawners to try to obtain the item. It hasn't worked any of the times.

How do I obtain a mob spawner item?

Comment: As far as I know you cant obtain Mob Spawner without mods.

Comment: There's a command for that in vanilla Minecraft; I'll try to find it.

Answer (score 6):

You can't obtain Mob Spawners in Vanilla Survival.

Comment: As a sidenote, most servers sell them for in-server prices.

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot get mob spawners. You can only use cheats to get them. I tried mining them with a Silk Touch Pickaxe, but nothing dropped.

If using cheats, type in `/give (username here) minecraft:mob_spawner` then get a spawn egg and activate it with it and I should summon the creature depending on which spawn egg you choose. Like a skeleton egg for example, will help the spawner spawn skeletons.

There is no way to do this in Vanilla Survival Minecraft. You need mods for this.

Answer (score -2):

In 1.15.2 I tried mining it with iron pick with Looting III and Silk Touch I and it workt i made a blaze stick generator with help of that on survival!

Comment: This is just wrong. Silk touch doesn't work on spawners. See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=beqY-0sg4Tw) for evidence.

Answer (score -3):

You can't unless you use mods.

Comment: I already answered the question with same answer (vanilla = no mods). Also the answer is wrong. You can get them if you are on Creative mode. We don't allow duplicate answers here.

Answer (score -4):

You can use a pickaxe, but it has to be very special You need a pickaxe with "Looting III, Efficiency V, Silk Touch I, and Unbreaking III" preferably diamond.